# npm packages out of sync

Tags: angular, npm

I have an Angular 4, ionic project that was working just fine untill I tried to add angular material.
Since then building fails with a variety of errors to do with packages being out of date or not installed. I have attempted to get everything up to date using

```
npm install npm-check-updates
```

and then running it with the update option

```
ncu -u
```

But building still fails. The latest output is:

> PS C:\projects\ghost> npm install rxjs@^6.0.0
> npm WARN @ionic-native/admob-pro@4.6.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @ionic-native/core@4.11.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2@4.5.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.12.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @ionic-native/sqlite@4.4.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @ionic-native/status-bar@4.12.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

I've tried installing them individually, you can see that the error above can from trying

npm install rxjs@^6.0.0

Trying to install ^5.0.1 it then complains about rxjs@^6.0.0 not being installed.

My current package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "ghost",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.7",
    "@ionic-native/admob-pro": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.12.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.12.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "angular-md5": "^0.1.10",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^7.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "^2.31.4",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "^1.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "4.4.3",
    "ng2-socket-io": "^0.1.7",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
        "BILLING_KEY": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiXowzRxSOngnQxjOye2KlNab0Trgan9mupsgoe9WfjCaMlFwj9GsMNYYHhWXpAelN0tx2kusW6IS+fPVTSTapwmFmNX2ssycKtVvRC9pSA5fDWo9Ez2z8MENjZ8m2K7fC//qLvYCiFuTB5sos2oMCqlGc36x6SKThk4R1kuJ+yBWijzOBmnEyQyAMRZ+gWltz7wMEWqTCz6w8u6LsJATF3F8KwXy9YGi46+Erixj1d8B26mABXAKomWuwfuhNUazGNNSSldbO9nCCbvq2QIa29odP1su0F1bgjRXuGrjFeKtrfHW8+7dns0g/lTWCPckVI53SLVL3DjtjV+3UmsDOQIDAQAB"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Advice needed please. And thank you.

Comment: Please hold, I just realized something

Comment: OK, nothing has changed, answer away